# What steps does an image editor go through to edit a JPEG?

Tags: jpeg

Say for example I want to a draw a red line across a JPEG image, what steps does an image editor go through to handle this?

Is it like the following?

1. Decompress JPEG into other file format (Ex. BMP)
2. Make modifications to image in this new file format

Comment: usually yes - it is decompressed to the format where every pixel has its own representation in memory, then converted again to jped

Comment: @0___________ What are some examples of file formats where every pixel has its own representation in memory? Or is BMP the only one?

Comment: why do you think that it has to be stored in the memory in any file format? U usually it is just a simple array.

Comment: @0___________ Ahh so if I decompressed a JPEG, I could just store the pixels in an array, and then modify the array values to edit the JPEG?

Comment: When it is decompressed it is not jpeg anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the image you need:

1. decompress the jpeg file and store the raw image in the memory
2. modify the image
3. compress and store as a file in jpeg format